# What do I need to configure in azure so that I can connect to a database located on another server and accessible only through a vpn?

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, vpn

I have an API that is implemented through the WCF service. This application has a database that is only available through a VPN connection. I tried to deploy this application on azure, however, when sending a request to some endpoint, I get a 502 error. I think this is due to the fact that my server is not connected to a VPN.

What do I need to configure on azure to connect to an existing VPN, or how can I solve this problem in another way?

Answer (score 0):

502 Error Is an error code generated when no response is received from the server.

According to your description, the server is not connected through VPN and the application needs to connect to VPN to access, which should be the problem you said. The link below is for a tutorial on setting up a VPN: https://www.rebeladmin.com/2016/12/step-step-guide-configure-site-site-vpn-gateway-connection-azure-premises-network/